# Postgres database post-expiration of user password unable to login

Tags: postgresql, password

I have a test environment where there exist 2 roles:

> group role with Superuser permissions (no login) and
>   user role that belongs to group.

When I trip the password to expire on this account I am unable to login again and therefore unable to change my password.  How is the user to change their password once the valid until expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another superuser has to change the password for this user. After succesfull login, the user can change his own password again.

Comment: What about in an environment where there is only 1 super user.

Comment: You have to change pg_hba.conf file to allow connections without password, restart the server (to reload the config file), connect without a password (no need anymore) and change your password. After this you have to edit pg_hba.conf again and reload the file again.

Comment: thank you very much Frank, if I had enough rep I would upvote your answer